# singularitygs mixing pixels and percentages in layout

Tags: singularitygs

I want to create a page with singularitygs that shall produce something like in

http://www.foreignpolicy.com/

What i want to achieve is, that the header sections width shall be 100% but the content section shall be centered with a max-width of : 960px. Both shall be responsive when they get smaller, exactly like on the above mentioned page

From what i understood at https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity/wiki, i can not create grids which have both px and % sizes.

Is there may be a workaround?

The thing is i am developing a template with the Drupal Omega theme and singularitygs plays very well with it.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone kindly give me some feedback. 
Thank you

Sorry for my bad english:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you cannot mix fixed and fluid columns without the [calc output style](https://github.com/Team-Sass/Singularity-extras/blob/1.x.x/stylesheets/singularity-extras/outputs/_calc.scss), having a fixed max-width section and a fluid section is totally do-able, just have more than one container.

Singularity is container agnostic, so the column widths will expand to fit into any container you place them. If the container is 100%, it will fill 100%. If the container is only 960px, it will fill 960px. The column widths are simply percentages of a whole, not a specific container.

Here's a [basic container layout](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9239304) that more or less accomplishes what you want

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I understand why singularitygs is so powerfull